# Define a function f1(x) object from an another function f0(x,y), but setting y to a fixed value c++

Tags: c++, std-function

Suppose I have a function

```
  void f0(double x, double parameters[]) { ... }
```

and I want to define a function object

```
  std::function <void (double x) >f1
```

such that, for example,  `f1(x) = f0(x,a)` where `a` is a specified set of parameters (e.g. `double parameters[4] = {1.0, 2.9, 6.2, 2.1}`)

How would I do this?  My thoughts are to try to have a function that inputs `a` outputs f1, but I'm not sure how to do this.

The motivation of this is that, in essence, I have yet another function FUNC in a library, that inputs a function with a single double input, but I want more flexibility to add parameters to that function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple with a lambda:

```
std::function<void(double)> f1 =
    [&parameters](double x) { f0(x, parameters); };
```

Alternatively, you could use `std::bind`.

```
using namespace std::placeholders;
std::function<void(double)> f2 = std::bind(f0, _1, parameters);
```

But I much prefer lambdas for almost any situation.

Comment: I'd recommend just using `auto` rather than `std::function` in the lambda solution, too. Less space used and probably faster function calling.

Comment: Please don't bind a lambda to a function object. Use auto instead.

Comment: @Otomo: If you can, yes. But sometimes you need a dynamically bindable/rebindable function object. That's why `std::function` exists, and I don't see why you shouldn't store a lambda in one. (that is to say, I don't see why you would single out lambdas, among all types of function objects, for being excluded from being used with `std::function`)

Comment: @Otomo: The question specifically asked for a `std::function` with that signature.